# Insert column from one table to another after copying

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run this query on SQL Server Management Studio. But I am getting an error. What I did initially was to copy a table from another table. the table from which I am copying is the painting table and I am trying to make a replica of that painting table, named as painting1. But the task was to copy all the columns except for 1.

```
painting 
col1, col2, col3, col4
```

The query used for this task is as below

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3  
INTO PAINTING1 
FROM PAINTING
```

After the creation of painting1, it has col1, col2 and col3 from painting table
Now the task was to insert the one remaining column into the replica table, so what I did to insert that remaining column to insert the replica table painting1 from painting table.

```
INSERT INTO PAINTING1 (col4)
SELECT col4 FROM PAINTING
```

And I run into this error:

> invalid column name 'col4'

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong,

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  If `col4` is not in both tables, you question is unclear.

Comment: Are there any changes done to `painting1` in the meantime? If not, drop it and recreate it as you did before but this time with the additional column.

Comment: @stickybit, I have to add the col4 in a separate query after I have replicated the col1, col2 and col3 from painting to painting1.

Comment: Your words betray you. You don't "insert a <new> column" into a table, you add the column (as already suggested) and then you need to populate it (if desired - that part is not clear). Quite frankly, this "lesson" is poorly designed and teaching bad habits IMO.

Answer (score 0):

First add the new column in the table `PAINTING1`:

```
ALTER TABLE PAINTING1 ADD col4 INTEGER;
```

Change `INTEGER` to the data type of `col4` that you want.

What you actually need is to update `PAINTING1` with the values of the column `col4` from `PAINTING`.
This can only be done if one of the columns `col1`, `col2` or `col3` is unique, like a primary key, so it can be used as the link between the 2 tables:

```
UPDATE p1
SET p1.col4 = p.col4
FROM PAINTING1 p1 INNER JOIN PAINTING p
ON p.col1 = p1.col1
```

I used `col1` as the link between the tables.
If `col1` is not unique, use all 3 columns in the `ON` clause (if their combination is unique):

```
ON p.col1 = p1.col1 AND p.col2 = p1.col2 AND p.col3 = p1.col3
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the table with col1, col2 and col3. How can it be anything but an error to  refeference col4 that doesn't exist?

You can of course add additional columns to the table at any time, but what you could do is add `col4` as part of your `select into`.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, '' as Col4  /* use / cast whatever data type it should be */
INTO PAINTING1 
FROM PAINTING
```